# Join operation on large datasets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bigdata, data-science, dask

How to apply inner join operation in two dataframes having 100k rows?.I have 8 GB Ram of computer and used Dask but still my computer get hanged.What is the proper solution?

```
          import pandas as pd
          import numpy as np

          import dask.dataframe as dd
          import time
          pool=mp.Pool(processes=4)
          start=time.time()
          SData = dd.read_csv("KD_111.csv")
          TData = dd.read_csv("KD_111_T.csv")
          SData["Unique"] = SData["OrderDate"]+ SData["Region"] +   (SData["Rep"]) + SData["Item"]
          TData["Unique"] = TData["OrderDate"]+ TData["Region"] + TData["Rep"] + TData["Item"]
          SData=SData.set_index("Unique")
          TData=TData.set_index("Unique")
          #Data1=SData.groupby(SData.index)
          #Data2=TData.groupby(TData.index)
          Data=dd.merge(SData,TData,left_index=True,right_index=True)
          #print(Data.columns)
          Data1=Data.loc[:,:"Total_x"]
          Data2=Data.loc[:,"OrderDate_y":]
          print(Data1.compute())
```

Comment: How about separate these files by join key?

Comment: Whenever i tried to compute or save dataframe to csv or any other file,my pc get hanged,may be some memory error.

Comment: Do not read the whole files at the same time, but read several lines of the file, separate them into different files and then read another several lines.

Comment: Thanx ,I will try

Comment: Reading file doesn't take time,but actual problem in converting to csv

Comment: Not needed any help from all those who just saw the question.I have already solved my problem by myself.Thanx Harper but i manage to solve.

Comment: np. Can you share how you solve it? I am very interested in it.